# GET Sometimes Lost

Tags: php, get

I'm totally rewriting an old legacy site to use more modern PHP and have a most unusual problem that I'm not sure how to even express which is that sometimes a GET doesn't get received from one page to another. The page loads with its header, menu and footer and there is otherwise no content.

Reloading the page, it's there and working again and it doesn't happen on any particular page but rather on anything that sends and receives GET and even then only occasionally. The the page is empty, a little diagnostic function in the footer shows that no GET was received even though it was there on the link that was selected. I'm not even sure where to start in trying to find what's happening so any ideas?

A GET might be something like this:

```
/categories/category.php?CategoryID=6
```

or

```
/categories/author.php?AuthorID=1
```

This is a portion of the diagnostic function used in the site's footer where it applies to GET which, whenever a page fails to load, shows nothing for GET:

```
$s = "\n<p><h4>GET Values</h4>\n\n";
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$value)
$s .= "<strong>$key</strong> = $value\n";

echo $s;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what 'received' means. Do you get a white page? An error? A browser window that's forever loading?

Comment: Create a page with just `<?php var_dump($_GET);`, add some query parameters to the page.   Does this work/deliver expected output?

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules?  Like Apache's modrwrite?  Try _Curl_ing a URL and checking response headers.

Comment: "Received" means that the page receiving it isn't and shows only the coded header and footer but no content. I didn't try a var_dump($_GET) but will. No rewrites.

Comment: Is there something above this code that prevents this code from being run? Or, is $_GET being set by accident? (e.g. `if($_GET = null) { }` ). You could try adding a `var_dump($_GET)` before the code runs to see if it's actually empty... and back track up the code from there.

Comment: That's just a GET URL. You aren't sending the GET information to another page. You are just loading a URL into the Browser.

Comment: Sounds like there's some JS code using the [_History_ API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) to do client-side URL manipulation. These don't result in HTTP requests to your web server

Comment: I created a test page containing `var_dump($_GET);` and it seems to consistently receive it but not on the actual site pages. The GET is indeed being sent because I can see it in the link being clicked but one thing I noticed in the Apache error.log is a "can't modify headers" error from one of the scripts that creates the log. Can header problems somehow block GET from getting through and if so, can it do it inconsistently?

Comment: The site has no JavaScript.

Comment: A few comments back, this `one of the scripts that creates the log` should have been `one of the scripts that creates the logo`

Comment: I added `var_dump($_GET)` to the visible top of a page and selected an item which had `/index.php?ID=1` but `var_dump($_GET)` sometimes received `array(1) { ["reload"]=> string(0) "" }` while other times it worked. The `?reload` issue is something I had posted in another question and was not resolved but I'm sure it's related to this issue. I'll try placing `var_dump($_GET)` in other places to see where it works consistently. This site's pages contain many included bits and pieces, such as header, menu, footer etc, so there is a lot to go through. Thank you all for your responses!

Comment: _“The ?reload issue is something I had posted in another question and was not resolved but I'm sure it's related to this issue.”_ - then it probably makes rather little sense, that we try and discuss your problem here, without you giving us the details of this “The ?reload issue” first of all. Can’t find what other question you might be referring to here, and if this is indeed relevant to the question you are asking here right now, then this belongs in this very question as well.

Comment: I posted the result of it in my comment when I mentioned it and the post says little more but here is the post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210351/after-apache-re-installation-browsers-giving-reload-in-url  In any event, I may have found the problem and will know for sure once more testing is done. There was a custom function being called that I’ve remarked out which seemed to at least at the ?redirect.